# How do I get Eigen::TensorRef to work for broadcast and other operations?

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor

I'm using Eigen 3.4 with MSVC. I have used `Eigen::Ref` before, with some success, and I am trying to use `Eigen::TensorRef`, but am running into issues:

```
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> A(3, 1, 2);
A.setValues({{{1, 2}},
             {{3, 4}},
             {{5, 6}}});

Eigen::array<int, 3> aBroadcast({1, 4, 1});
auto lazyBroadcastA = A.broadcast(aBroadcast);
const Eigen::TensorRef<const Eigen::Tensor<double, 3>> ref(lazyBroadcastA);
```

This code does not compile, due to the last line. I get a number of errors:

```
'Dimensions': is not a member of 'Eigen::TensorBroadcastingOp<const std::array<int,3>,const Derived>'   
'IsAligned': is not a member of 'Eigen::TensorBroadcastingOp<const std::array<int,3>,const Derived>'    
'Layout': is not a member of 'Eigen::TensorBroadcastingOp<const std::array<int,3>,const Derived>'
```

The same thing happens when I try to construct from `Eigen::TensorCwiseUnaryOp` and `Eigen::TensorReductionOp`. Am I doing something silly, or are these ops just not supported?

Comment: I've replicated this error here: https://godbolt.org/z/3Pz3935Pj

Comment: What do you expect `lazyBroadcast` to be?  The `eigen` library sometimes does interesting things when using `auto`.

Comment: I expect it to be an `Eigen::TensorBroadcastingOp`, which it is. Then I want to lazily evaluate this operation into a `TensorRef` so that I can get the dimensions of the output tensor.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the lazy broadcasting is a `Eigen::TensorBroadcastingOp` which as I understand it is a preparatory entity to actually accomplish a task within `eigen`.  Most ops have an `eval` method which does the computation.  Again, my limited understanding is that ops get evaluated automatically when the assignment operator is used.

So to get your reference you need to `eval()` that op first like this:

`const Eigen::TensorRef<const Eigen::Tensor<double, 3>> ref(lazyBroadcastA.eval());`

The other way I was able to get that tensor was:

`Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> A2 = lazyBroadcastA;`

When I print the result I get this:

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, but the problem isn't getting a `Tensor`. The point is that I want lazy-evaluation of the tensor operation, since I only really want to know the dimensions of resulting tensor and I don't want the performance overhead of constructing the whole thing.

Comment: The Eigen documentation for a `TensorRef` even states: "A reference to a tensor expression. The expression will be evaluated lazily (as much as possible).`

Comment: @Danny I'm pretty sure `Eigen::Ref` needs a matrix as well.  If I try to do something like `Matrix3d a, b;... auto c = a * b; ... Ref<Matrix3d> ref(c);` a compiler error will occur.  Yes just tried it with MSVC and got `no instance of constructor...`

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, but you are incorrect about `Eigen::Ref`. Here is a basic working example: https://godbolt.org/z/bMd45nx9v

Comment: @Danny "In the const case, if the input expression does not match the above requirement, then it is evaluated into a temporary before being passed to the function."  You didn't follow my example and used a `const` which is evaluated into a temporary.  Remove the `const` and it will fail to compile.

Comment: Oh man, thanks for the clarification. In that case, does `Eigen::TensorRef` simply not implicitly evaluate a temporary like `Eigen::Ref` does? I'm disappointed that `Eigen::Ref` doesn't do what I expected. I was hoping for a clean/generic way of extracting dimensionality from Eigen operations, but it looks like there really isn't a way around either performing the evaluation sometimes, or manually wrangling whatever information each operation type has exposed.